# robots.txt allows & disallows few pages, what does it mean for other pages?

Tags: robots.txt

I was going through many websites' robots.txt files to check if I could scrape some specific pages. When I see following pattern -

User-agent: *
Allow: /some-page
Disallow: /some-other-page

There is nothing else on robots.txt file. Does it mean that all other remaining pages on the given website are available to be scraped?

P.S. - I tried googling this specific case but no luck.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: @JohnConde I'm not writing robots.txt file for my website. I have posted this question because I need to gather some data from other websites and I wanted to make sure that I wouldn't be scraping something which I shouldn't. So it's not about SEO but about scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [website](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt), Allow is used to a allow a directory when it's parent may be disallowed. I found this [website](https://varvy.com/robottxt.html) quite useful as well.

> Disallow: The command used to tell a user-agent not to crawl particular URL. Only one "Disallow:" line is allowed for each URL.
>
> Allow (Only applicable for Googlebot): The command to tell Googlebot it can access a page or subfolder even though its parent page or subfolder may be disallowed.

Regarding your question, if the remaining pages aren't included in a Disallow directory, you should be okay.